# Tag not firing on Pardot form in iFrame

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, pardot, conversion-tracking

I'm trying to set up conversion tracking for Pardot forms set up in iFrames. I've added the HTML code to the forms thank you page and set up 2 tags in Google Tag Manager. It looks like my second tag is not firing and I'm not sure why. I will post code and steps I've taken so far.

Thank you page code:

```
     <script>

    try {

 parent.postMessage(‘iframeTestPageLoad’, ‘https://www.websitename.com‘);

} catch(e) {

 // Something went wrong…

 window.console && window.console.log(e);

}

   </script>
```

Listener Tag 1 in Google Tag Manager:

- tag with custom HTML
- trigger fires on all pages

  window.addEventListener(‘message’,function(){

       if (event.origin === “https://go.pardot.com“ && event.data === ‘iframeTestPageLoad’) {

          window.dataLayer.push({‘event’: ‘formSubmit’});

       }

       else {

         console.log(‘the tag did not work’)

       }

     },

       false)

Tag 2 to send info to GA:

- track type is Event
- custom event trigger named 'formSubmit'

When testing in preview mode and submitting form Tag 1 is being fired but not Tag 2.
When running this with Dev tool I see the following errors:
"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" associated with website in iFrame code.
When I click "view frame source" on form I can find this website used in code....

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/Static/_fonts.css">
```

Any help on this would be much appriciated!